# java.sql.SQLException: Method not supported on using HikariCP with Hive JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, hive, connection-pooling, hikaricp

I am using MySQL as meta store for hive.

In my JDBC code, I replaced

```
DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUri, username, password);
```

to

```
 HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource();
 ds.setJdbcUrl(connectionUri);
 ds.setUsername(username);
 ds.setPassword(password); 
 return ds.getConnection();
```

I got following exception:

```
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Method not supported
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:514)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:107)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:94)
at com.impetus.idw.data.connector.utils.JDBCUtil.getJdbcConnection(JDBCUtil.java:173)
at com.impetus.idw.data.connector.utils.JDBCUtil.checkTableExistence(JDBCUtil.java:66)
at com.impetus.idw.data.connector.datasource.HiveTable.exists(HiveTable.java:146)
at com.impetus.idw.data.connector.tools.hive.HiveToHiveCopyBaseTest.testMetadata(HiveToHiveCopyBaseTest.java:25)
at com.impetus.idw.data.connector.tools.hive.LocalToLocalTest.testHive(LocalToLocalTest.java:19)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Method not supported
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.setReadOnly(HiveConnection.java:1271)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.setupConnection(PoolBase.java:372)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:346)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:508)
... 31 more
```

**Does HikariCP supports Hive JDBC?**

Is there any way to avoid call to `org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.setReadOnly` method?

Comment: HikariCP supports drivers that adhere to the JDBC specification; the `Connection.setReadOnly` is not allowed to be not implemented (supported). And as it is only a hint according to the API doc, the simplest way to support it might be as simple as ignoring any calls to it (although I haven't checked if the specification goes into more detail).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use latest (> 2.0.0) hive driver. See [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-11501) resolved in hive.